# Intelli-J (Java) runs in parent folder. So it printing the current folder gives the parent of the project folder

Tags: intellij-idea

After migrating to JDK17 and JUnit 5 I did first some cleaning. This works works OK also for other projects.

When I execute a simple test in Intelli-J (Java), I see that the test is run in the parent folder as base folder.

So, when I do a simple printCurrentFolder() ... then it prints the parent folder of the project folder.

How can I correct that? Anything changed?

I tried many things like:

- Running Maven tests - works ok
- File > Clear cache etc
- Remove '.idea' folder.
- Remove any *.iml file (after closing the project).

When running the JUnit test, I can see this run configuration:

[image]

Comment: What run/debug configuration type do you use? Most configurations have a setting for the working directory.

Comment: See the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/9TOKDYt.png.

Comment: Thank you. The screenshot of my working environment is shown in the question. Before this, this was never a problem of many years.

Comment: Try `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` instead.

Comment: As described in my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69410668/104891.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` as the **Working directory** for your JUnit run configurations. You can [make it the default as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69410668/104891).