Intellij global system properties
I need to add custom properties to read in in java with System.getProperty("custom_property") in all intellij projects (macOS).
I read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties?input_string=jvm+properties.
My custom vm options are in  /Users/name.lastname/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/idea.vmoptions, default vm options are in /Users/name.lastname/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions.
Those files are different, shouldn't they have been copies of each other? I tried to add my custom property in the custom vm options with
-Dcustom_property=test
but it didn't works, System.getProperty("custom_property") got null.
I managed to add the property to a single tomcat instance, but I would like to add the property globally, for all intellij tomcat instances.
What's wrong?

idea.vmoptions contains the options for the JVM that is running IntelliJ, but it sounds like you want to configure the options of the JVM that runs your Java programs. Is that right?

You can edit template configurations per https://stackoverflow.com/a/69410668/104891.
